# How does LocalSystem determine computer name for network credential?

Tags: windows, windows-7, samba

I'm using the `LocalSystem` account to try to connect to a network share.

It should be using `COMPUTERNAME$` as the network credential.

According to the remote logs, it is actually trying to use `OLDCOMPUTERNAME$`, which is properly refused.

The workstation was at one point renamed from OLDCOMPUTERNAME to COMPUTERNAME. I'm not sure what method was used to do the renaming.

Running `regedit` as `LocalSystem` (via `psexec -s -i`), there was a reference to OLDCOMPUTERNAME in

Key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa\CachedMachineNames`

Value: `NameUserPrincipal REG_SZ "OLDCOMPUTERNAME$@domain.fqdn"`

I changed it manually and rebooted, but this did nothing.

The workstation is domain joined, and connects properly otherwise. A script that runs at shutdown (as `LocalSystem`) needs access to a network share.

Where could `LocalSystem` be taking an obsolete machine name from to use as a network credential?

Comment: Just to be sure: the computer object, DNS-name, etc. in AD is properly renamed? I'd also check the ADSI attributes in the attribute editor of the computer object.

Comment: 1. The DNS shows no sign of OLDCOMPUTERNAME, neither it nor the domain controller resolve it to anything. Not hiding in a hosts file.

Comment: [Sorry, pathetic comment editing]

2. Re: renaming object, see below.

3. ADSI show no sign of the old name.

Then:

1. Joined a test machine, verified it had access to the share via `OLDCOMPUTERNAME$`.

2. Renamed the computer _at the workstation_. COMPUTERNAME propagated to the domain, DHCP lease, DNS.

3. I then renamed the machine _again_, using `netdom renamecomputer` from the domain controller. Newest name propagated correctly, but testing using `psexec -s -i cmd` shell _still_ used OLDCOMPUTERNAME credential.

More to come...

Answer (score 0):

Removing and rejoining the computer from the domain causes the `LocalSystem` network credential to be set correctly to `COMPUTERNAME$`.

Microsoft's interfaces for renaming a computer in a domain leave the machine in an indeterminate state.

Edit: this solution is now 1 for 2: worked on one machine, had no effect on another.